# What is the best approach to utilizing the graphics card in java for a "newbie"

Tags: java, gpu

I'm a student in computer engineering and I am working on a game engine and small game to be built on top of it. As we add more and more to the project, it gets clearer that we are not going to be able to render everything that we'd like using just the CPS. Some faster CPU's like my desktop can handle the game rendering, but laptops are getting quite slow.

As of right now, I have been only using the Java.Awt graphics class to accomplish rendering. I have also been optimizing what needs to be rendered and have tried to make it so that only things that the user can see is actually rendered. Unfortunately, my efforts have not made a large enough impact which points me down the road of using a graphics based library.

I had already tried using OpenGL, but the language is so primitive that it is very hard to understand and due to my lack of understanding is not really moving forward much. If anyone has another library that could utilize the graphics card more effectively without such a steep learning curve, I would love to hear about it and where I could learn more.

Note: The entire engine has been built from the ground up and is not built on any libraries at this moment.

Comment: JavaFX?  There are any number of bindings for OpenGL (and probably DirectX) for Java, although the "general" rendering pipeline is already configured to run through these anyway

Comment: look at aparapi it is pure java for computing. also look at java3d and similar graphics engines.

Answer (score -1):

Swing might work. You can import it using `import javax.swing.*;`
Pretty sure you use it by extending JFrame and JPanel. Or I might just be thinking about AWT. Hope this helps!

**EDIT:** Extending JFrame and JPanel **IS** Swing. [Look at the first example in this site for help.](http://www.lsv.fr/~sankur/java/first.html)

Comment: This aanswer does not address the problems mentioned in the original question

Comment: I am suggesting something, not addressing the problems.